# create an infinite loop to build a REPL in scheme

Tags: scheme, infinite-loop, read-eval-print-loop

It strikes me beautiful, how i can create a REPL in Common Lisp using:

```
 (loop (print (eval (read))))
```

However, since I'm a complete noob in Lisp (and dialects), I miserably failed to achieve the same in Scheme, due to the lacking `loop` function.
I tried to implement it as

```
(define (loop x) x (loop x))
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything (even when called as `(loop (print 'foo))`

So the question is: how to implement an infinite loop in Scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (loop x) 
  x 
  (loop x))
```

This is an infinite loop when you call it. But it does not erad, evaluate or print. It takes an argument `x`, evaluates it then throws it away before callng itself with the same argument and it repeats.

For a REPL you want something like this:

```
(define (repl)
  (display (eval (read))) ; for side effect of printing only
  (repl))
```

Usually a REPL has a way to exit:

```
(define (repl)
  (let ((in (read)))
    (when (not (eq? in 'exit))
      (print (eval in))
      (repl))))
```

Comment: my implemention attempt was only directed at the `loop` itself, so i could then use `(loop (print (eval (read))))` as in CL. i still don't understand why it doesn't work. otoh, recursing `(repl)` strikes me as very nice as well...